why isn't this baking correctly?
i hope i included just enough context here.

you can see the bake settings, and the low poly selection being the active one in those two selections, but when i bake it displays this plane looking empty bake in the editor there.
i think i'm copying this guy correctly at 10:10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etazbacPCJA&t=618s

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Have you checked the normals? If they point downwards, baking will not work because the rays will not hit anything.

In the Image Texture node try changing the source of the image from Single Image option to Generated.

